# Simplified coding for summary table

Tags: vba, excel

I am writing a macro to create a summary based on the counting from my raw data. 
Each case has 100+ rows, there are 20 cases with different value.

[image: raw data]

I want to show a summary like this: the green area represents the counting of all rows with value above 20. Pink represent total sum for all counting.

[image: result]

To do this, I wrote:

```
Range("A2") = "Total"
Range("A3") = "Case 1"
Range("A4") = "Case 2"
Range("A5") = "Case 3"
Range("A6") = "Case 4"
....
```

And for the green field, I wrote:

```
Range("B3").formula = "=COUNTIF(T:T, "">""20)"
Range("B3").formula = "=COUNTIF(T:T, "">""20)"
Range("B3").formula = "=COUNTIF(T:T, "">""20)"
Range("B3").formula = "=COUNTIF(T:T, "">""20)"
....
```

As you can predict, I have many, many code lines for each cell in the table.
 Is there any simplified way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
Dim n as Long, rng As Range

Set rng = ThisWorkBook.Range("A2")

For n = 1 to 20
    rng.Offset(n, 0).Value = "Case " & n
    rng.Offset(n, 1).Formula = "=COUNTIFS(S:S,""Case " & n & """,T:T,"">20"")"
Next n
```

Comment: Your first post also worked great! I was very thrilled at applying the codes to some of my existing macros!

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("YourSheetNameHere")
    .Range("A2").Value = "Total"
    .Range("B1").Value = "Category"
    .Range("S2", .Range("S" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Address).Copy .Range("A3")
    .Range("A3", .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Address).RemoveDuplicates 1, xlNo
    .Range("B2").Formula = "=COUNTIF(T:T,"">20"")"
    .Range("B3", "B" & .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Formula = _
        "=COUNTIFS(S:S,A3,T:T,"">20"")"
End With
```